# How to select several CSS classes and apply Javascript logic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, anchor

On a website, I have several buttons to ask for a demo.
Each button is an anchor tag that point to the same link, a mailto direction. The email direction changes depend on the country you selected.
So I made this logic:

```
    function changeEmailAdress(){
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("#ar") != -1){
          document.querySelector(".mailToRef").href="mailto:argentina@globalnewsgroup.com";
        }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#br") != -1){
          document.querySelector(".mailToRef").href="mailto:brasil@globalnewsgroup.com";
        }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#us") != -1){
          document.querySelector(".mailToRef").href="mailto:usa@globalnewsgroup.com";
        }else{
          document.querySelector(".mailToRef").href="mailto:demo@globalnewsgroup.com";
        }
    }
```

This is the html:

```
<a id="mailto" href="" target="_blank" class="cta cta--accent mailToRef">Solicitar Demo</a>

<a href="" class="c-navigation__item mailToRef">Contacto</a>

<a href="" target="_blank" class="cta cta--lg mailToRef" data-solicitude="demo" ">Accedé a una Demo</a>
```

The Javascript code works perfectly only when I have one anchor tag with "mailto" class. Then, when I add the class to the other links It does not work.

I tried using "querySelectorAll" but it does not work either.
How can I make it work? I think I am missing something but I can not figure out what it is.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll(".mailToRef").forEach((el)=>{
    el.href="mailto:brasil@globalnewsgroup.com";
});
```

It returns an array, so you should use `forEach` to loop through it.

Comment: The OP didn't want the href to be identical for all anchor tags. Your answer does that.

Comment: @Dejazmach Actually, I interpreted it that way. The OP wants to send you to the `brazil` demo and contact if you clicked on brazil. Why would scrolling down to the brazil section (denoted in OPs code with the #ar/br etc.) give you non brazil emails?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all elements with `mailToRef` class and assign the individual anchors by their index.

```
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".mailToRef");
function changeEmailAdress(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("#ar") != -1){
      anchors[0].href="mailto:argentina@globalnewsgroup.com";
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#br") != -1){
      anchors[1].href="mailto:brasil@globalnewsgroup.com";
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#us") != -1){
      anchors[2].href="mailto:usa@globalnewsgroup.com";
    }else{
      anchors[3].href="mailto:demo@globalnewsgroup.com";
    }
}
```